# Intersection of decreasing sequence of compact connected set is connected.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Suppose that $F_1, F_2, F_3, . . .$ is a sequence of connected, compact subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F_1 ⊃ F_2 ⊃ . . . .$ Show that $K= \bigcap F_n$ is connected.

My approach:If possible, suppose not.
Let, $f$ be a two valued continuous defined on $K$.
Now $K$ is a closed subset of $F_1$,so by Tietze extension theorem we can extend $f$ to a continuous function $f_1:F_1\to\mathbb{R}$.
Since, each of $F_i$ is connected so $f_1(F_i) ⊃ [0,1]$.
We claim $f_1(K)⊃ [0,1]$.
Let, $y\in [0,1]$ then $f_1(x_n)=y$ where $x_n\in F_n$.This $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence converging to some $l\in F_1$.Now as $F_n$ being a decreasing sequence of compact sets and $l\in F_n$ and hence $l\in K$.Since, $f_1$ is continuous, $f_1 (l)=y\in f_1 (K)$.Thus, our claim is proved which contracdicts our hypothesis as $f_1(K)=f(K)$ is a two valued function.Hence, done!

Is is correct?Any suggestion?Thanks.

Comment: To use Tietze's theorem, you have to prove the space is normal.

Comment: It's a metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. In fact, it generalizes to the case that $F_1$ is a *metrizable* subset of an arbitrary space $X$.